# Rails Tests with RSpec and Capybara can't find links in application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm using RSpec and Capybara to write feature tests for my Rails app and the my tests are failing with the error message:

```
Failure/Error: click_link "Google"

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible link "Google"
```

My spec is written as:

```
 it "lists logged in user's profile data" do
      visit '/'
      mock_auth_hash
      click_link "Google"
      click_link "User"
      expect(page).to have_content('mockuser')
    end
```

My Google login link_to is in my application.html.erb layout:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link"><%= link_to 'Google', '/auth/google' %></a>
```

When I take the same link_to and put it into my root page the test passes without a problem. It seems very likely that Capybara is not picking up the HTML in my application.html.erb layout. I am unsure how to fix this though, and Capybara's documentation does not indicate any solutions.

Any help provided is appreciated.

Comment: Is the link_to visible in the dom? If it's not, e.g. has a style that sets it's visibility or display value to hidden then capybara won't find it. It is possible to use `visible: false` in your capybara selector... but that wouldn't make much sense as a user can't click a link they can't see. I would try some debugging with `js: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that Capybara is just ignoring some part of your page, and much more likely that your app isn't actually rendering that layout correctly when rendering your page (maybe because you're rendering a link inside a link - which is illegal html https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element - for some reason??).  Sleep for a couple of seconds after the `visit` and then if the driver you are using supports screenshots - take one, if not use `save_and_open_page` and inspect the HTML to see what is actually on the page.

```
visit('/')
sleep 3
save_and_open_screenshot # If the driver supports screenshots
# save_and_open_page # To look at the actual HTML
```

Odds are you'll find the page really doesn't have that link on it.

Comment: Hi Thomas, you were correct that I had a link within another link class. What was interesting is Rails (or the browser) was smart enough to make that link work, but obviously this was causing Capybara to fail.

Comment: @maxking Capybaras default `rack_test` driver is much stricter about having valid HTML than most browsers (which will ignore and try to interpret ,sometimes differently, as much broken HTML as possible).  If this answer solved your issue don't forget to accept it (the checkmark) so your question gets marked as answered.

Comment: Adding a delay between visit() and find() solved a problem I was having with some random element that I was positive was always there just causing some tests to fail randomly in the background possibly due to lower process priority or something.

Comment: @NickM Rather than adding a delay - pass `wait: 10` (or larger value if needed) as an option to the `find` call so it will wait longer than normal for the element to become available

Comment: Thanks. I have set it at 1-2s depending on spec but I guess sometimes the SPA doesn't do all its business that fast... or something else was blocking it, not sure. Now it works, I don't mind spending 10s extra on that test rather than digging through all sorts of code and settings :)

Comment: @NickM It won't waste a full 10 seconds -- the `wait` option is the maximum amount of time it will wait -- if the element appears sooner it moves on -- so it would really only slow down failures (since it won't fail until 10 seconds has passed and the element hasn't appeared)

Comment: I’ll try it. Thank you Thomas, very much appreciated. This site needs a button to send beer to people!